# Showing FontIcon on NativeScript dialog

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Is it possible to show fonticon on Nativescript dialog? Something like this?

```js
dialogs.alert({
  title: // set icon as text
  message: "Check-in Successful"
}).then(()=> {
  console.log("Dialog closed!");
});
```

Can title be set something like FontAwesome string i.e. String.fromCharCode(0xe903). How can we set the class to the title so that it is reflected as FontAwesome icon?

I am trying to show following dialog on successful login.

[image]

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the below link, there are some styling limitations for the dialogs module discussed [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3830)

Implementing the solution as mentioned in post to create a custom modal dialog box

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmROQAjiekk

Answer (score 0):

As mention by @RajanPhatak there are some styling limitations for the dialogs.

If you want a customizable dialog, check this awesome plugin https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fancyalert